# "borrowed value does not live long enough" error in trie insertion

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a simple trie implementation where an `Edge` contains a character and a reference to another `Node`:

```
struct Edge<'a> {
    ch: char,
    to: &'a Node<'a>,
}
```

A `Node` contains a vector of edges:

```
pub struct Node<'a> {
    edges: Vec<Edge<'a>>,
}
```

I'm trying to implement the method to insert/get a character into a node. I think the return value should be a reference to a `Node`: if the character is already in one of the edges, then we directly return the existing `Node`; if not, we return the newly created `Node`. This is where I get into trouble:

```
impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    fn get_or_create(&mut self, ch: char) -> &Node<'a> {
        match self.edges.binary_search_by(|e| e.ch.cmp(&ch)) {
            Ok(idx) => {
                return &self.edges.get(idx).unwrap().to;
            }
            Err(idx) => {
                let to = &Node { edges: Vec::new() };
                let e = Edge { ch: ch, to: to };
                self.edges.insert(idx, e);
                return to;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `to` is said to not live long enough.

I'm quite sure what I wrote is far from idiomatic Rust. Initially when I included the reference to `Node` in `Edge`, I didn't add the lifetime parameter, and was prompted to do so, then I had to add it everywhere. However it looks quite weird. I wonder what would be the correct way to do it?

Maybe what I should really have used is some other wrapper type abstraction in `Edge` to refer to heap-allocated `Node`, e.g. `Box`? I shall read the section on this topic in *The Rust Programming Language* carefully.

Comment: If the `Edge` contains a reference to a `Node`, you need a place to "store" the `Node`. The `Node` needs an owner. Your data structure does not look able to do that.

Comment: You could [try reference counting instead if that is suitable for you](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=26407a3243e4bb68167b547339af1fc5&version=stable&backtrace=0). I never know if this is idiomatic though because I haven't actually implemented any sort of custom, self-referential data structure in Rust yet.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead why do you say self-referential? I don't think there's any loops in the references; said another way, it's a tree, not a graph.

Comment: Whoever downvoted here, care to explain? And how would you approach this problem instead, if you think this question is pointless and the answer is so self-evident?

Comment: @Shepmaster Right. Is that because of the property of tries (only one incoming edge for a node)? If there are multiple edges that can point to the same node, surely I'll need some sort of reference then?

Comment: @Shepmaster Heh.. off to a great start today :| Honestly I thought it was self referential on my initial pass, which is why I went the `Rc` route. I need more coffee I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data structure can't work as designed. The red flag is the following sentence:

> I think the return value should be a reference to a `Node`: if the character is already in one of the edges, then we directly return the existing `Node`; if not, we return the newly created `Node`.

The code doesn't return the newly created node, it attempts to return a *reference* to the newly created node. Returning a reference to an object is only safe if the object is stored in a place where it will outlive the reference. Otherwise the reference would end up pointing to the location on the stack where the object used to reside, resulting in a crash when used. Mistakes like this one were a frequent source of crashes in C and C++ and are precisely the kind of bug that Rust's borrow checker was designed to prevent.

Rust tracks reference lifetimes using the lifetime parameter on functions and data. To prove that the reference will not outlive the object, Rust prohibits the lifetime of the reference to extend beyond the lifetime of the object. Since the new node is dropped at the end of the function and the reference is returned from the function, the object's lifetime is too short and the code is correctly rejected as invalid.

There are several possible fixes:

- Store the `Node` directly inside `Edge`. This was [shown to compile](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=63851321357d79f2d902ad303e5d51e0&version=stable).
- Change `&Node` to `Rc<Node>`. This allows shared ownership of a single node by more than one edge, and automatic deallocation.

In both cases explicit lifetime management will no longer be necessary, and ownership will "just work". If you know C++11, an `Rc<>` is roughly equivalent to a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Shepmaster You are right, I missed the part where node refers to edges through vector. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: I would discourage using an `Rc` here because it adds overhead that isn't needed - there will never be a node owned by more than one thing.

Comment: @Shepmaster Just talked to my lecturer and he suggested that one could still use `Box`, since then Rust can know the size of the structure inside precisely and thus save a bit memory. If we store it directly inside, we would probably need to `shrink` from time to time because Rust might overallocate. Not a big saving but still. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Shepmaster I offered `Rc` as an option because the OP hinted at sharing of nodes in a comment: *If there are multiple edges that can point to the same node, surely I'll need some sort of reference then*

Comment: @JIXiang Using a box instead of inline storage can save memory when uised inside an `enum` where inline storage can needlessly enlarge the whole `enum`. (This might have been the use case your lecturer referred to.) Using a box inside a `struct` would end up requiring *more* memory (because you need the space for the pointer and the separate space for the allocated block), more fragmentation and less memory locality to boot.

Comment: @JIXiang no, that doesn't really make sense. The compiler *always* knows the exact size of `Node`, and it doesn't change during the program execution. A `Box<Node>` might be *smaller* than `Node`, but the overall memory requirements would go up (still need to allocate the `Node` and now store the pointer) and then there's extra indirection (and access time) to get to the actual details inside the `Node`.

Comment: @user4815162342 pedantically, it could reduce the *size* of either the enum or a struct, but in both cases the memory usage would go up (always for a struct, only when that variant is used for the enum).

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, you get a net savings from boxing only provided that the larger variant is sufficiently rare. The book *Programming Rust* by Blandy and Orendorff gives an example of this when discussing an enum that describes JSON data, most variants of which are primitive types, and one variant is a `HashMap`. It makes sense to box the hashmap to reduce the size of the whole enum.